# Selecting particular column using Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

i am having a file in hdfs which is comma `(,)` separated, I am trying to extract 6th column using scala for that i have written below code

```
object WordCount {
 def main(args: Array[String])
 {
 val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxx/xxx")
 val word = textfile.filter( x => x.length >  0 ).map(_.replaceAll("\\|",",").trim)
 val keys = word.map(a => a(5))
 keys.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/xxx/Sparktest")
 }
}
```

but the result i am getting in HDFS is not what i want.

**Previously my data was :**

```
MSH|^~\&|RQ|BIN|SMS|BIN|2019||ORU^R01|120330003918|J|2.2
PID|1|xxxxx|xxxx||TEST|Rooney|19761202|M|MR^^M^MR^MD^11|7|0371 HOES LANE^0371
```

**Now my data is :**

```
\
T
I
,
1
N
\
T
I
,
1
N
\
T
I
```

**I want my result yo be :**

```
BIN
TEST
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong. Please help

Comment: why am i getting down vote ? can you please explain so i can correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing `|` with `,`, but you're not *splitting* by comma, so `word` still has type `RDD[String]`, and not `RDD[Array[String]]` as you seem to expect. Then, `a => a(5)` treats each string as an array of *chars*, thus the result you're seeing.

Not sure why you'd replace the pipes with commas in the first place, you can just:

```
val word = textfile.filter(x => x.length >  0).map(_.split('|'))
val keys = word.map(a => a(5).trim)
```

Comment: Thanks ! This solved my problem. I have two doubts i want to know when to use split() in scala and how can i extract multiple columns
e.g; if i want BIN 2019 as my result can i use val keys = word.map(a => a(5)(6).trim) ?

Comment: You can read about `split` here: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-split-string-example; To get two columns separated by space you can use string interpolation: `word.map(a => s"${a(5)} ${a(6)}")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'split()' function!

```
val s="MSH|^~\\&|RQ|BIN|SMS|BIN|2019||ORU^R01|120330003918|J|2.2"

// WRONG
s.replaceAll("\\|",",")(5)   
res3: Char = ~

// RIGHT
s.split("\\|")(5) 
res4: String = BIN
```

Comment: if i want to extract multiple columns like i want BIN 2019 as my result how can i achieve this ?

Comment: @Captcha : s.split("\\|") returns an array. If u need something like BIN 2019 i would say  s.split("\\|").map(tuple => (tuple(5),(tuple(6)) in the above mentioned code

Comment: @Rakshith i followed what you said now i am getting results as
(BIN,20121009151949) how can i remove the brackets "()"

Comment: @Captcha : So basically the return type is a tuple . So if u say something like val tokenised :(String,String)= s.split("\\|").map(tuple => (tuple(5),tuple(6)) . So tokenised._1 will return you BIN and tokenised._2 will return you 2019. If u want them to be a string then you can concatenate tokenised._1 and tokenised._2

Answer (score 0):

In spark 2.0 now you have csv reader so you can simple load csv as follows

```
val baseDS=spark.read.option("header","true").csv(filePath)
  baseDS.show()
```

You can select column by simply its name as follows

```
val selectCol = baseDS.select(ColumnName)
```